# Different data structure to hold the below data other than map in java

Tags: java

I want to store data in a structure as shown below. There is a map which stores values in another nested map -

```
Key               Value
                  (Key)           (Value)
B1       -->   TradeRef  ----> "tradeRef1" 
               Dealdate  ----> "DealDate1", 

B2       -->   TradeRef  ----> "tradeRef2"
               Dealdate  ----> "DealDate2"
```

I have developed a solution, which is working fine. Is there any better approach to solving this problem.

The problem I have with my approach is that a lot of array list are being created.  Furthermore, if the numbers of a key of a super map increase like B1 AND B2 and later on let us say a new key B3 introduces then again a new array list will be introduced. For this reason please advise me in any alternative approach to achieve the same result for this problem.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> mapOfMapOfStrings =   new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();

HashMap<String, List<String>> b1Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
HashMap<String, List<String>> b2Map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();      

ArrayList<String> B1tradeRefList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> B1dealDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> B2tradeRefList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> B2dealDateList = new ArrayList<String>();

B1tradeRefList.add("tradeRef1");
B1tradeRefList.add("tradeRef2");
B1dealDateList.add("DealDate1");
B1dealDateList.add("DealDate2");

B2tradeRefList.add("tradeRef33");
B2tradeRefList.add("tradeRef44");
B2dealDateList.add("DealDate22");
B2dealDateList.add("DealDate24");

b1Map.put("TradeRef", B1tradeRefList);
b1Map.put("Dealdate", B1dealDateList);

b2Map.put("TradeRef", B2tradeRefList);
b2Map.put("Dealdate", B2dealDateList);

mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B1", b1Map);
mapOfMapOfStrings.put("B2", b2Map);
```

**Can this problem be solved by using any other data structure** (for example trees or linked lists) in an efficient manner? Or maybe by creating a custom data structure? 
I wish to explore the custom data structures implementation of the same above functionality other than my nested map solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't just use a class:

```
class Trade {
    String tradeRef;
    Date dealDate;
}
```

then you can simply have a `Map<String, Trade>` without the unnecessary nesting and duplication of keys. This approach is faster, safer (since you have an explicit class instance), and uses less memory than nested maps with constant keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot but still not able to grasp the complete picture then how would i add the things specific to B1  and B2 as i have shown request you to please code a little bit that will help to understand more Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be familiar with the use of classes by now in Java...this is a simple data-only class. How you actually use it must depend pretty strongly on your actual application.

Comment: @nneonno well i think the pojo that is advise by you in which the member variables must be of type <String> for example class Trade {
  Private List < String> tradeRef;
 Private  List<String> dealDate;
}

Comment: Sure, if that's what you need. (Seriously, I don't know your application well enough to dictate what you do - that's your job - I'm here just to make suggestions!)